# how to make android menu , and how to open new screen when choose an item in this menu

Tags: android

i'am new in android programming
so wanna to ask for something
i made a menu and respond to action of menu with this code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    // Handle item selection  
    switch (item.getItemId()) {  
    case R.id.main:    
        setContentView(R.layout.test2);   
        return true;  
    case R.id.news:       
        setContentView(R.layout.test2);             
        return true;  
    case R.id.feature:       
        setContentView(R.layout.test1);    
        return true;  
    default:  
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }
```

all of this items turn me to a new layout , what i need is , when select an item i can make a new codes and programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to read the [Android fundamentals article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) (especially the *ActivatingComponents* section).

A menu should start a new activity. If you want to change the content of one activity I would recommend to use tabs ([TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)).

---

So here's what to do (or at least what I suggest):

Create a new activity (e.g. `MyTaskActivity`). Add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `application` tag:

```
<activity android:name="your.pacakge.MyTaskActivity" />
```

And call this in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyTaskActivity.class));
```